# How to get data from two tables by removing duplicates based on few column values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables with same number of columns but with data different at few columns.

Example: 1st table data

```
 Apt_ID  Res_ID    Subject       SartTime              EndTime           Color 
   0       1        Avail    06-10-2015 08:00:0    06-10-2015 08:30:0     Blue 
   0       1        Avail    06-10-2015 08:30:0    06-10-2015 09:00:0     Blue
   0       2        Avail    06-15-2015 08:00:0    06-15-2015 08:30:0     Black
```

Result from 2nd table

```
 Apt_ID  Res_ID    Subject       SartTime              EndTime           Color 
   1       1       Booked    06-10-2015 08:00:0    06-10-2015 08:30:0     Blue 
   2       1       Booked    06-10-2015 08:30:0    06-10-2015 08:40:0     Blue
```

What I need is:

1. I need to merge records from both the tables, then replace
   records in first table with second table records if values at
   Res_ID , startTime and endTime columns are matched.
2. If a records from table_2 falls between start and end time slot in table_1,

I need to replace record in table_1 and add a new records for remaining time slot (please refer to second row in table 1 and 2).

Expected result:

```
  Apt_ID  Res_ID    Subject       SartTime              EndTime           Color 
   1       1        Booked    06-10-2015 08:00:0    06-10-2015 08:30:0     Blue 
   2       1        Booked    06-10-2015 08:30:0    06-10-2015 08:40:0     Blue
   0       1        Avail     06-10-2015 08:40:0    06-10-2015 09:00:0     Blue
   0       2        Avail     06-15-2015 08:00:0    06-15-2015 08:30:0     Black
```

Hope I make sense, If not please let me know.

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying my best to get this done.So far I have tried using "UNION" but as columns values are not same, records are not replaced and are duplicated. Also I'm working on this by using cursors but want to know if there's a efficient solution.

Comment: I suggest you to try right join sql query

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Turns out MySQL doesn't support the full join syntax. Thanks @jarlh--I'm always surprised when something I think is fundamental SQL isn't in MYSQL. However it can be emulated adequately using a UNION of RIGHT and LEFT joins. I'll show that below.

I had to read that question a few times, but I think I understand at least part of what you are asking.

You definitely don't need a CURSOR. You could probably use a UNION, but I would use a FULL JOIN and COALESCE to produce the result set.

--create test data

```
CREATE TABLE Avail (Apt_ID INT,  Res_ID INT,  Subject VARCHAR(10), StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, Color VARCHAR(10))
    INSERT INTO Avail (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (0,1,'Avail','06-10-2015 08:00:00','06-10-2015 08:30:0','Blue')
    INSERT INTO Avail (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (0,1,'Avail','06-10-2015 08:30:0','06-10-2015 09:00:0','Blue')
    INSERT INTO Avail (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (0,2,'Avail','06-15-2015 08:00:0','06-15-2015 08:30:0','Black')

    CREATE TABLE Booked (Apt_ID INT,  Res_ID INT,  Subject VARCHAR(10), StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, Color VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO Booked (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (1,1,'Booked','06-10-2015 08:00:0','06-10-2015 08:30:0','Blue')
    INSERT INTO Booked (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (2,1,'Booked','06-10-2015 08:30:0','06-10-2015 08:40:0','Blue')

--get the combined result set, preferrin values from the booked table.
    SELECT COALESCE(b.Apt_ID,a.Apt_ID) Apt_ID
          ,COALESCE(b.Subject,a.Subject) Subject
          ,COALESCE(a.Res_ID,b.Res_ID) Res_ID
          ,COALESCE(a.StartTime,b.StartTime) StartTime
          ,COALESCE(a.EndTime,b.EndTime) EndTime
          ,COALESCE(b.Color,a.Color) Color
      FROM Avail a
           FULL JOIN 
           Booked b ON a.Res_ID=b.Res_ID
                   AND a.StartTime=b.StartTime
                   AND a.EndTime=b.EndTime
```

EDIT: Using the full join emulation for MySQL:

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.Apt_ID,a.Apt_ID) Apt_ID
      ,COALESCE(b.Subject,a.Subject) Subject
      ,a.Res_ID
      ,a.StartTime
      ,a.EndTime
      ,COALESCE(b.Color,a.Color) Color
  FROM Avail a LEFT JOIN Booked b ON a.Res_ID=b.Res_ID
                            AND a.StartTime=b.StartTime
                            AND a.EndTime=b.EndTime
UNION
SELECT COALESCE(b.Apt_ID,a.Apt_ID) Apt_ID
      ,COALESCE(b.Subject,a.Subject) Subject
      ,b.Res_ID
      ,b.StartTime
      ,b.EndTime
      ,COALESCE(b.Color,a.Color) Color
 FROM Avail a RIGHT JOIN Booked b ON a.Res_ID=b.Res_ID
                                 AND a.StartTime=b.StartTime
                                 AND a.EndTime=b.EndTime
```

EDIT 2: Boy that is harder in MySQL than TSQL. Making do without a FULL JOIN, ISNULL, ROW_NUMBER, or CTE. There's almost certainly a better way to do this, but it appears to work.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49bb5/2) shows this. You would want a temp table, but SQLFiddle.com was complaining.

```
CREATE TABLE Avail (Apt_ID INT,  Res_ID INT,  Subject VARCHAR(10), StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, Color VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO Avail (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (0,1,'Avail','2015-06-10 08:00:00','2015-06-10 08:30:0','Blue');
INSERT INTO Avail (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (0,1,'Avail','2015-06-10 08:30:0','2015-06-10 09:00:0','Blue');
INSERT INTO Avail (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (0,2,'Avail','2015-06-15 08:00:0','2015-06-15 08:30:0','Black');

CREATE TABLE Booked (Apt_ID INT,  Res_ID INT,  Subject VARCHAR(10), StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, Color VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO Booked (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (1,1,'Booked','2015-06-10 08:00:0','2015-06-10 08:30:0','Blue');
INSERT INTO Booked (Apt_ID ,Res_ID,Subject,StartTime,EndTime,Color) VALUES (2,1,'Booked','2015-06-10 08:30:0','2015-06-10 08:40:0','Blue');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (Apt_ID INT, Subject VARCHAR(10), Res_ID INT, StartTime DateTime, EndTime DateTime, Color VARCHAR(10), rn INT);

SET @row_number=0;

INSERT INTO tmp (Apt_ID , Subject , Res_ID , StartTime , EndTime , Color, rn)
SELECT Apt_ID , Subject , Res_ID , StartTime , EndTime , Color, 
       (@row_number:=@row_number+1) rn
  FROM (
          SELECT COALESCE(b.Apt_ID,a.Apt_ID) Apt_ID
                  ,COALESCE(b.Subject,a.Subject) Subject
                  ,a.Res_ID
                  ,a.StartTime
                  ,a.EndTime
                  ,COALESCE(b.Color,a.Color) Color
              FROM Avail a LEFT JOIN Booked b ON a.Res_ID=b.Res_ID
                                        AND a.StartTime=b.StartTime
                                        AND a.EndTime=b.EndTime
            UNION
            SELECT COALESCE(b.Apt_ID,a.Apt_ID) Apt_ID
                  ,COALESCE(b.Subject,a.Subject) Subject
                  ,b.Res_ID
                  ,b.StartTime
                  ,b.EndTime
                  ,COALESCE(b.Color,a.Color) Color
             FROM Avail a RIGHT JOIN Booked b ON a.Res_ID=b.Res_ID
                                             AND a.StartTime=b.StartTime
                                             AND a.EndTime=b.EndTime
        ) x
  ORDER BY Res_ID,StartTime,EndTime

SELECT Apt_ID, Subject, Res_ID
      ,CASE WHEN COALESCE((SELECT EndTime FROM tmp b WHERE b.Res_ID = a.Res_ID AND b.rn = a.rn - 1),0) > StartTime 
            THEN (SELECT EndTime FROM tmp b WHERE  b.Res_ID = a.Res_ID AND b.rn = a.rn - 1)
            ELSE StartTime END StartTime
      ,EndTime
      ,Color
 FROM tmp a
```

Comment: Does MySQL support full outer join?

Comment: Thanks Karl for the solution, It almost works except for the part where the result does not show the records need to be split. For example in table_1 I have an appointment record available from 8.30 - 9.00 , where as in table_2 I have an appointment booked from 8.30 - 8.40. So in end result I need to show booked appointment from  8.30 - 8.40 and available appointment from 8.40 - 9.00. Please refer to  second and third rows in expected result.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, that's related to what I meant by " I think I understand at least part of what you are asking."

Comment: Thanks Karl. Your solution works perfectly for data I provided. I was changing data and was testing the query and got stuck in a situation where if there are two records from 8.00 - 8.30 and 8.30 - 9.00 in available table and a record form 8.00 - 8.45 in booked table. I would like to show booked record for 8.00 - 8.45 and available record from 8.45 - 9.00 in the result. Any suggestion to achieve this ? Once again thanks for all the help.